# What's the point of the <option> "label" attribute inside <select>?

Tags: html

Besides the fact that only IE7+ supports it, why would you use something such as [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp)? Namely:

```
<select>
  <option label="Volvo">Volvo (Latin for "I roll")</option>
  <option label="Saab">Saab (Swedish Aeroplane AB)</option>
</select>
```

After all, 'Latin for "I roll"' and 'Swedish Aeroplane AB' are *lost* (i.e., only remain in the source code).

Comment: According to w3schools, IE7 also does not support it: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In that example, the **long** text will be sent to the server when the form is submitted.

Given the existence of the value attribute, it is redundant.

Comment: Thank you. So I gather that, if the "value" attribute were present, the long text would be irrelevant, right? Pretty disconcerting...

Comment: can you elaborate on this? what is the precedence of text content, label, and value?

Answer (score 16):

As per the [definition of the option tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) by the w3c  :

*"This attribute allows authors to specify a shorter label for an option than the content of the OPTION element. When specified, user agents should use the value of this attribute rather than the content of the OPTION element as the option label."*

David's answer is pretty good, I just wanted to add a link to the official definition. :D

Answer (score 12):

**The `label` attribute explicitly sets the label.** Allow me to improve your example:

```
<select>
  <option label='Volvo (Latin for "I roll")'>Volvo</option>
  <option label="Saab (Swedish Aeroplane AB)">Saab</option>
</select>
```

The text content of `<option>` is used as default for both: the visual labeling and the “technical” form/script value for that option. You can overwrite the default for each with the `label` and the `value` attribute, respectively.

All three can be accessed by Javascript.

**Firefox did not support `label` in `<option>` for 20 years** and [fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40545) it in version 77 (2020-06-02). (It “always” worked in `<optgroup>`, though.)—Or should I say “almost fixed it”: the implementation breaks some new cases: [regression](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1644611).

Thus, my current recommendation: always use the text content of `<option>` for the label text and overwrite the “technical” value with the `value` attribute if needed. Avoid the `label` attribute on `<option>` elements if you care about Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

We can test what's used for what:

```js
for (const opt of document.getElementById('sel').children) {
  console.log(`label: "${opt.label}", text: "${opt.text}", value: "${opt.value}"`)
}
```

```html
<select id="sel">
  <option label="Label">Text</option>
  <option>TextOnly</option>
  <option label="LabelOnly"></option>
  <option value="Value" label="Label">Text</option>
</select>
```

Output:

```
label: "Label", text: "Text", value: "Text"
label: "TextOnly", text: "TextOnly", value: "TextOnly"
label: "LabelOnly", text: "", value: ""
label: "Label", text: "Text", value: "Value"
```

The tl;dr is that the text (*inside* the option) is used for both the value and label if they're omitted.

The label is what the user sees on the screen. Contrary to (my) expectations, that means it overrides the text.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: the `label` attribute serves no practical purpose today.

Per the [HTML 4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6), the `label` attribute was intended "for use in hierarchical menus", such as the following:

```html
<SELECT name="ComOS">
     <OPTION selected label="none" value="none">None</OPTION>
     <OPTGROUP label="PortMaster 3">
       <OPTION label="3.7.1" value="pm3_3.7.1">PortMaster 3 with ComOS 3.7.1</OPTION>
       <OPTION label="3.7" value="pm3_3.7">PortMaster 3 with ComOS 3.7</OPTION>
       <OPTION label="3.5" value="pm3_3.5">PortMaster 3 with ComOS 3.5</OPTION>
     </OPTGROUP>
     <OPTGROUP label="PortMaster 2">
       <OPTION label="3.7" value="pm2_3.7">PortMaster 2 with ComOS 3.7</OPTION>
       <OPTION label="3.5" value="pm2_3.5">PortMaster 2 with ComOS 3.5</OPTION>
     </OPTGROUP>
     <OPTGROUP label="IRX">
       <OPTION label="3.7R" value="IRX_3.7R">IRX with ComOS 3.7R</OPTION>
       <OPTION label="3.5R" value="IRX_3.5R">IRX with ComOS 3.5R</OPTION>
     </OPTGROUP>
 </SELECT>
```

A browser that supports HTML4 would render something like this:

```
  PortMaster 3
      3.7.1
      3.7
      3.5
  PortMaster 2
      3.7
      3.5
  IRX
      3.7R
      3.5R
```

Older browsers which don’t recognize the `<optgroup>` tags would render this:

```
  PortMaster 3 with ComOS 3.7.1
  PortMaster 3 with ComOS 3.7
  PortMaster 3 with ComOS 3.5
  PortMaster 2 with ComOS 3.7
  PortMaster 2 with ComOS 3.5
  IRX with ComOS 3.7R
  IRX with ComOS 3.5R
```

In 2023, you're probably not concerned about those old browsers so you can pretend like the `label` attribute on `option` doesn't exist.