# HTML select shows value instead of text

Tags: html, html-select

Is it possible in a `html select`, to display the value of the option instead of the text?

It's gonna be used for displaying a long disription in the dropdown, but when selecting it should only be showing a short text/ the value of the option.

code:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">This is a long long text, that explains option 1</option>
    <option value="2">This is a long long text, that explains option 2</option>
</select>
```

Now the selected item, when you leave the dropdown/combobox/whatever, should only display '1'

Comment: Show your code.. it may help to understand what you have tried

Comment: I have updated the question, is it really not possible?

Comment: You might want to use the label attribute:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905984/whats-the-point-of-the-option-label-attribute-inside-select

Comment: Put your value return code in value=your_code" that's it.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it by using the label tag:

```
<option value="the_value" label="the text displayed">the hidden text</option>
```

Comment: "label" attribute is not supported in Firefox. Also, you will see only label text in dropdown menu and the same text when dropdown is closed. In that example, "the hidden text" will be sent to the server when the form is submitted. Given the existence of the value attribute, it is redundant.

Comment: Firefox now appears to support the label attribute on option element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution.

```
$("select option").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("data-label", $(this).text());
});
$("select").on("focus", function () {
    $(this).find("option").each(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).attr("data-label"));
    });
}).on("change mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).find("option:selected").text($(this).val());
    $(this).blur();
}).change();
```

Comment: It does not work if user focused on the select element and leave without selecting any option.

Comment: @Rickyrock do you means "mouseleave" doesn't work in your case?

Comment: @JeffreyNeo When a user clicks on the select tag, but leave as it is without selecting other options.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that might solve your problem:

HTML:

```
<select id="countryCode">
   <option data-text="his is a long long text, that explains option 1" value="1">This is a long long text, that explains option 1</option>
   <option data-text="his is a long long text, that explains option 1" value="2">This is a long long text, that explains option 1</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#countryCode option:selected').html($('#countryCode option:selected').attr('value')); // already changed onload

$('#countryCode').on('change mouseleave', function(){
    $('#countryCode option').each(function(){
      $(this).html( $(this).attr('data-text') ); 
    });
    $('#countryCode option:selected').html(  $('#countryCode option:selected').attr('value')   );
    $(this).blur();
});
$('#countryCode').on('focus', function(){
    $('#countryCode option').each(function(){
        $(this).html( $(this).attr('data-text') ); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9y43gh4x/

Comment: In mobile, it does not work if user focused on the select element and leave without selecting any option because there is no mouseleave event. Also, user able to see that text is changed from "his is...." to "1". Micro seconds delay....

Answer (score 0):

I think This may help you

```
<select id='cboSelect'>
 <option value="1">This is a long long text, that explains option 1</option>
 <option value="2">This is a long long text, that explains option 2</option>
</select>
```

Try this jquery

```
$("#cboSelect").change(function(){    
   $("#cboSelect option:selected").text($("#cboSelect").val());
});
```

this will change the text of the selected option with its corresponding value

Here is the fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepaksuresh3003/YUxYu/9/)

Comment: Hmm yea, I think there is no answer to the thing i wanted.

Im gonna go another way to "solve" my problem

Thanks for responding ..

Comment: This will change the value for forever. That is not what expected out of it.

Answer (score -1):

Just don't give a value:

```
<select>
    <option>Test</option>
</select>
```

Will submit `Test` when selected.

Just place the values you put in `value` as the text.

You can't have it show the value in `value=` just like that.

Comment: I have updated the question, is it really not possible?