# HTML select - display value attribute in HTML but retain option text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of `option` states in a `select` element.

```
<select>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
</select>
```

I need the browser to display just the abbreviation of the state (which is presently stored in the `value` attribute) but the opened pull-down menu should still display the full name of the state.  So a user will see and select "Arizona" in the pull-down menu and then the closed pull-down menu would display "AZ".

The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699172/html-select-show-value-instead-of-text) was close, but it replaces the `option` text with `value`'s value, so it does not work for me.

I'd like to use JavaScript / JQuery for this, but kudos to any wizard who can do this with just HTML and CSS.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: Pretty sure that can’t be done with HTML and CSS alone.

Comment: What's point of doing this? This requires a hacky solution as there is no event like `open` and `close` for `select` elements. Also it can confuse the users. If you really want to do this then I recommend using a custom select menu.

Comment: @Vohuman, actually, using jQuery's `focus` and `blur` will reflect an open and close state.

Comment: The point is to save space in the form while have the full word available in the pull-down menu.

Comment: @Vohuman Are there any custom menus you can recommend that would accomplish this?  I wouldn't be against using JQueryUI, but a quick search of custom select menus didn't immediately lead me to something that would do the trick.

Comment: @Vincent Well, the custom select boxes should be customized in this case :) As pointed out by ^James you can listen to `focus` and `blur` events and use a rather hackish solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you're still looking for an answer, here's how I would do it.

First off, I don't see much use-case doing this. It seems like a lot of effort just to abbreviate a word the users can read easily anyway. Though, here it is.

Because there's no real way to check the last selected unless we store it in a variable and then iterate the list to bring back the name when the user selects the input, it requires a great deal of effort. Though, we can store the data within the select inside an array, then persist that data wherever we want. I wouldn't recommend using data directly out of an HTML element in this case, but for now, you can see in the following example that storing the states within an array does the trick.

The following answer requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyc15z5y/3/), or run the code:

```js
;(function() {

    var states = [];
    var customSelect = $('.js-select');
    var customSelectOptions = customSelect.children();

    // Get each state then push them to the array
    // Initial state declaration
    customSelectOptions.each(function() {
        var state = $(this).text();
        states.push({ state: state });
        if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
            $(this).text($(this).attr('value'));
        }
    });

    // On focus, always retain the full state name
    customSelect.on('focus', function() {

        customSelectOptions.each(function(index) {   
            $(this).text(states[index].state);
        });

        // On change, append the value to the selected option
        $(this).on('change', function() {

            customSelectOptions.each(function(options) {
                if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                    $(this).text($(this).attr('value'));
                }
            });

            // Un-focus select on finish
            $(this).blur();

        });

    });

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this did the trick.  The only change I needed to make was adding to `customSelect.children()` another `.children()` because in the full list I have `optgroup`s so I needed to drill down one level deeper.

Comment: One issue I noticed when kicking the tires: when you select the list but do not make a change (e.g., you select the same item or you click elsewhere to close the pull-down menu), it displays it as the full name of the state. I tried adding `blur` and `focusout` events to `.on`, but both led to strange behavior. `click` and `mouseup` didn't work either. Any ideas on how to modify to avoid this?

Comment: Same thing also happens when you tab over it but don't make any changes when tabbing through the form.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I didn't consider using `blur` and `focus` events. If using jQuery is an option:

```
$('select').on('blur focus', function (e) {
    $(this.options).text(function () {
        return e.type === 'focus' 
               ? this.getAttribute('data-default-text') 
               : this.value;
    });
}).children().attr('data-default-text', function () {
    return this.textContent;
}); //.end().on('change', function () { $(this).blur(); }).blur();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0vre3cmg/

Comment: That's a nice solution!

Comment: @Mottie Thanks :), the idea of listening to `focus` and `blur` events belongs to James.

Comment: @Vohuman, no worries buddy, you finalised this so much damn cleaner! too!

Answer (score 1):

Definately can't be done in HTML and CSS.. JS is necessary here.

Well you can use "change()" jQuery function to handle the action of changing options. Then you can take `selected` option value by attribute 'selected' and put it as selected option text, then use "click()" on select element and return the option text to original.

This is tricky game and not clean.

Other option would be to create some container to store value of selected option. In this case you will need to style this container as select button and when it's clicked the select element will be clicked (more javascript here).

In your case I would search for a nice looking and powerful select element plugin, that would grand your needs.

Answer (score 0):

javascript will be required to do this. I put together [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zsnvLv9o/) using Chrome, so the width of the select might need to be adjusted to make it look good in all browsers.

CSS

```
select {
    width: 12px;
    border: 0;
    /* text-indent: -999em; */ /* or hide text so the width can be set higher */
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="select-value"></span>
<select>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function(){
        $('.select-value').html( this.value );
    }).change();
});
```

---

Update: To alleviate the concern of making the text clickable, a bit more code could be added, and then repositioned over the select ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zsnvLv9o/1/))

CSS

```
select {
    width: 50px;
    border: 0;
    text-indent: -999em;
}
.select-value {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('select').on('change', function () {
        $('.select-value').html(this.value);
    }).change();

    $('.select-value').on('click', function () {
        $('select').focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: This feels a extremely hacky replacing the select view with raw HTML. An accessibility disaster in real-world use case.

Comment: it's not replacing the select, it's just making it very narrow so the dropdown arrow is still clickable, and you can still tab into it.

Comment: Hmm. On mobile this isn't quite the story, as you can't actually select it unless you thumb is directly on the arrows.

Comment: Maybe the css can be modified to hide the select text and keep the arrow visible; something like `select { width: 30px; border: 0; text-indent: -999em; }`

Comment: This solution is close, but the thing I don't like about it is that users will often click the text to look for the pull-down menu, and when they don't find it they may get confused.