# Different text in select options then the one displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the requirement to design a select input box where the options have a longer piece of text with information (attribute data-display), but when one is selected, I would only like to display a shorter version (attribute value) (which will be the value that is submitted).

eg.

```
<select>
    <option data-display="level1" value="1"></option>
    <option data-display="level2" value="2" selected></option>
    <option data-display="level3" value="3"></option>
</select>
```

Here for example when i see the input box, I would like to see as text "2". But when I click on it to select an option I would like to see the three descriptions, WITHOUT changing the selected text "2" to "level2".

I hope you guys understand what I mean.

edit:
Here is an image of the behavior that I'd want:

Only options in dropdown show "data-display"

[image]

And when the option is selected, I'd only like to see the number.

Comment: _“I hope you guys understand what I mean.”_ - nope, not at all. Not one single bit. What texts are you talking about - your options don’t contain any? And what “three descriptions”?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but it sounds like you just need to use the text and `value` of the `option` elements properly

Comment: @CBroe, I believe what he means is that when an option is selected it should display the value, but when he clicks to select an option the data-display should be shown, and when clicked only the value stays active.

Comment: This is going in your direction, try it out and change the source of the values as needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822596/html-select-display-value-attribute-in-html-but-retain-option-text

Comment: much is unclear here, but especially this part: `I would like to see the three descriptions`...

Comment: @CBroe, not that complicated to understand apparently if quiet a few other people managed to. N. Ivanov got what I meant, the only crucial thing that all other solutions don't solve, is that when clicking to select an option ALL texts switch back to the data-display text. I would only like the dropdown options to change, and not the display one.

Comment: Look at @Redo 's answer, which is almost what i'd like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add 2 event listeners, 1 for `focus` and 1 for `change`.

the `focus` should change the `innerHTML` to it's data-display value and the `select` should change it's `innerHTML` to it's value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').focus(function() {
    $('option').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).data('display'));
    });
  }).on('change', function() {
    $('option').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).blur();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option data-display="level1" value="1">1</option>
    <option data-display="level2" value="2" selected>2</option>
    <option data-display="level3" value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost exactly what I wanted!
Would it be possible to NOT change the selected input's text when clicking on the select? For example if I now click on your example, the selected input which previously was "2" changes to "level2".

Comment: Well then simply check if the option is selected, before you modify its text content ...

Comment: @CBroe ,I added an image to my question to clear up my request.. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can’t have that, because what it displays on top actually _is_ the selected option. If you want it to say “2” there, then you will have to live with that the options shown in the dropdown will read “level1”, “2” and “level3” at the same time.

Comment: that's not possible with native select. you have to create a custom select field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom select like [this](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render) one for jquery and use custom templates to render items and menu. Use given callbacks like `_renderButtonItem`, `_renderItem`, `_renderMenu` to provide an element with the desired info and template.
Another option is to use the [theming/templating options](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#themes-templating-responsive-design) of [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) library.