# How to prevent the HTML dropdown box to show its Label as the display text in Chrome?

Tags: php, html

The select box is like,

```
<select tabindex="4" name="dir_state[]" id="dir_state1">
 <option value="District of Columbia" label="Distcol">District of Columbia</option>
</select>
```

In Google Chrome browser, the above drop down shows the Label value ie "Distcol" as the display text rather than "District of Columbia"

So how to change it to show "District of Columbia" in Chrome ?

Comment: Remove the label attribute?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3906894/989920

Answer (score 1):

Html `option` has only two attributes.

`value` and `selected`.

So, remove the `label` attribute.

Comment: Exactly.
The label is used on the `optgroup`, not the `option`. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option