# How to get the label to populate in Chosen dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

Ok. So, after 2 hours of searching and debugging, I found out that chosen.js plugin won't populate the dropdown with the label/values from the original dropdown.

My original dropdown:

```
<select id="mySelectId">
  <option label="test" value="test"></option>
</select>
```

If my dropdown is modified like this, it works fine:

```
<select id="mySelectId">
  <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```

How do I let chosen to see the labels instead?

Comment: You should give more explanations.

Comment: @PhilMaGeo about the chosen plugin? or my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I learned something new today.  I never knew about the label attribute of `<option>`.  However after reading about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905984/whats-the-point-of-the-option-label-attribute-inside-select), I would suggest not using it.

1. It's not supported on a major browser (Firefox).
2. The same effect is achieved by placing the label between the opening and closing option tags`<option>label</option>` as you outlined above.

Modify your `<option>` tags accordingly, and then you will be able to get chosen.js to work properly.

Comment: Wow. I never noticed that in firefox. Thank you for that.